# Dependency isssue on Skype Installation in Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, skype

I tried Below 2 packages,but both were faled. I even tryed to install missing dependencies, but that also again asking some another dependencies. Is there any other approch to install skype on Debian 6 ?

```
skype-debian_4.0.0.7-1_i386.deb
skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb
```

Error Detail of 1st package:

```
root@debian:~/skype-install# dpkg -i skype-debian_4.0.0.7-1_i386.deb
Selecting previously deselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 56273 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-debian_4.0.0.7-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-dbus is not installed.
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-network is not installed.
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-xml is not installed.
 skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4 is not installed.
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
root@debian:~/skype-install#
```

Error Detail of 2nd package:

```
root@debian:~/skype-install# dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb
Selecting previously deselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 56273 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-dbus is not installed.
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-network is not installed.
 skype depends on libqt4-webkit (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-webkit is not installed.
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-xml is not installed.
 skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4 is not installed.
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
root@debian:~/skype-install#
```

Comment: Why didn't you install the dependencies?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton , Tried to install one by one , but it intern asking some other dependences ,, Something look like an endless process ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `apt` does not have any means of installing locally downloaded packages so you can't take advantage of its dependency resolution and `dpkg` doesn't have dependency resolution. So you are in a catch-22 here.

The solution is to use `gdebi` to install the package. It will resolve the dependencies, install them, and finally install your locally downloaded package. (If you don't want the GUI, then install `gdebi-core`.)

```
apt-get install gdebi-core
gdebi skype-debian*.deb
```